# Open Serial Port CMD

Tags: windows, cmd, serial-port

I try to open one serial port in CMD of Windows 7. I used the command `echo "say" >\\.\COM25`, but i need that the port still open because when execute the command only transmit and close the port. 
Does anyone know how can i develop this thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep a serial port open for a sequence of commands by using a subshell, and redirecting the subshell's output.

But batch really is not suitable for serial port interaction.  Pick a programming language that lets you hold a handle to the serial port and doesn't rely on redirection.

Answer (score 1):

You could try putty to facilitate the use of COM ports.

https://www.putty.org/